# Writing mocha test for nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am a beginner to nodejs, I need to know how to write a mocha test for nodejs for variable definitions.

for example,

if i had a object like this,

```
var objectName = {

     fileName : '',

     filePath : ''

}
```

Then how can write a mocha test for this variable definition. Please help me to write a test code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect those semicolons shouldn't be there.

Comment: ya ofcourse separated by , i will just edit it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't test this kind of stuff usually, but can make something like (using chai.expect) :

```
var obj = {
  name:''
};

describe('My object definition', function(){
  it('should give me an empty name', function(){
    expect(obj.name).to.equals('');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Ya i do understand but i have my object this way,             var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public/images/uploadImages')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        console.log("req.body"+req.body.file);
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + file.originalname)
        emitter.emit('file-upload',file.fieldname + '-' + file.originalname);       
    }
});           I need to test this stuff.. still i didnt get clear idea in testing this object definition.

Comment: Your question isn't the same. You sould better open a new question with your full case, because it's not the same at all actually

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792205/writing-mocha-test-for-file-upload-using-multer   I have already added a seperate question regarding this . But i didnt get any response for that. That,s why i thought to learn from start of simple object definition.